# Functional discrepancy within PCBA batch

Tags: pcb-assembly, manufacturing, component-failure, manufacturing-process, quality

When manufacturing a small prototype batch of an embedded system at EMS I have detected different behavior between the units. All units work as expected, except that some units fail to operate same pump properly when it is controlled at a high speed (the drive displays some hick-ups and breaks when the speed increases). Approximately half of the batch functions flawlessly.

I have visually inspected the boards and measured values of critical passive components without noticing any issues. Next step will be throrough scope measurements.

While I cannot share the design I would like to ask expirienced members of the community:

When noticing a discrepancy within a batch of PCBA - what are some most common causes that go undetected by optical inspection?

Comment: It may be a design error instead of manufacturing error. They may be manufactured correctly. That's something you can't visually detect.

Comment: There's the ever popular "components with slightly different properties."  You can see (on a visual inspection) when a component doesn't meet the expected specifications.  Maybe you've got two batches of transistors that behave differently.  They might meet the manufacturing specifications, but just marginally meet the requirements of your circuit.  That can apply to diodes, transistors, ICs, and just about all other electronic components.

Comment: Can I ask what is "EMS"?  Also: What number of devices did you get made?  (Size of _n_ matters for different failure distributions.)

Comment: EMS is Electronic Manufacturing Services. Batch size is 20.

Comment: Have you done any WCS to determine that you are ok even with max production spread? For 20 units, it's likely that all components come from the same reel, so there shouldn't be much spread from the start, but still.

Comment: @winny ... what is "WCS"?

Comment: Worst Case Scenario.

Comment: I have considered this and verified that all important parts come from the same tape/reel.

Comment: The specific case is solved - I was wrong and one of the used ICs came from two different cut tapes. Turned out they worked differently despite being same part number.

Comment: Did you check if there is an actual difference on the component level? What was your EMS provider's answer to the complaint?

Comment: No, and component manufacturer did not go into any detail, just claimed that the parts must have been exposed to moisture/esd/soldered at wrong profile, and claimed no batch differences are known. Not impossible, but still a bit sus as the chips actually worked, just slighly worse in certain high speed scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a manufacturing error and not a design error, here is my top list of most likely culprits:

- **Differences in soldering temperatures during reflow soldering.** Reflow ovens generally switch heating elements on and off to achieve their desired temperature. This can cause a fluctuation of temperatures of ±10°C, which may have caused some boards to not reach the required soldering temperatures of typically >217°C.
- **Insufficient paste.** Since you are mentioning that you are driving pumps, there may be a problem with whatever controls them. If you have MOSFET transistors on your board, insufficient amounts of paste on a ground pad could be the problem.
- **Batch problems on a component level.** Maybe alternative items have been used or components were sourced from different suppliers.